# Phone number for FSS besides 1800wxbrief

Tags: cell-phone, fss

Are there other "local" phone numbers to reach FSS besides 1800wxbrief?

The answer seems to be "yes," but does anyone know where to find them?

Thanks

Comment: if you search for FSS numbers in Alaska, you can find them on the FAA's website [link](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/AK_Aviators_Safety_Handbook_2017_ver3.pdf) Page 10

Answer (score 5):

Alaska is unique in continuing to offer local Flight Service Stations.  In the lower 48 states, weather stations have been automated and FSS functions have all been consolidated into a single call-center location.

So to answer your question, there are no "local" flight service stations any more in the lower 48.  You can find more background information by doing a word search on "consolidation of flight service stations."

Comment: In the first paragraph you say that Alaska has local Flight Service Stations and in the second paragraph you say there are no more local Flight Service Stations.

Comment: I added "lower 48" to the second paragaph for clarity.

Comment: What about Hawaii?

Comment: @Someone, good question, not sure.  If I have time to research further I will modify my answer...